# If-else extension

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I like using this extension if I need to perform conditional action on an object:

```
T IfTrue<T>(this T source, Func<T, bool> shouldPerform, Action<T> action) {
    if (shouldPerform(source)) {
        action(source);
    }
    return source;
}
```

But I was wondering what would be the best solution if I need both `true` and `else` actions? I image use should look like:

`someObject.IfTrue(self => ValidateObject(self), self => self.TrueAction()).Else(self => self.FalseAction());`

One of the possibilities I thought of was adding additional parameter to `IfTrue` method:

```
T IfTrue<T>(this T source, Func<T, bool> shouldPerform, Action<T> trueAction, Action<T> falseAction = null) {
    if (shouldPerform(source)) {
        trueAction(souce);
    } else if (falseAction != null) {
        falseAction(source);
    }
    return source;
}
```

But then I end up using it in

`someObject.IfTrue(self => ValidateObject(self), self => self.TrueAction(), self => self.FalseAction());`

and not having it with additional `Else` extension.

So, my question: can this be split up into two separate extensions (note: both extension should still return `T`)?

Comment: Why would you use this instead of an `if/else` statement? `source` is already in scope so you don't need to return it.

Comment: @Lee I use my `IfTrue` extension if I need to chain it with other methods. And returning it back allows to add another method to the chain afterwards.

Comment: the problem is that the chaining of iftrue suggests that the chain has different things depending on the result (like linq `where`), in this case it doesnt.  This just looks like Fancy Code Syndrome

Comment: If all you want is to propagate `this` between method calls you might as well write a more general `T Tap<T>(this T, Action<T> act)` method and embed the `if/else` logic inside that.

Comment: That feels like one extension method too far..!

Comment: @DovydasSopa But you're gaining noting by chaining the methods.  Just don't chain the methods and you're code will improve dramatically.

Comment: @Servy I'm just interested if that's possible. I already thought of extension which takes both true and false actions. Thought two part extension would be nicer to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most comments said - there is no easy way to build If-True-Else extenstion with two separate `If` and `Else` parts, so I ended up making this one:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
internal static T If<T> (this T source, Func<T, bool> isTrue, Action<T> thenAction, Action<T> elseAction = null) {
    if (isTrue (source)) {
        thenAction (source);
    } else {
        elseAction?.Invoke (source);
    }
    return source;
}
```

This extension can take both `then` and `else` actions and still be able to just have only `then` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could have `IfTrue` return a new class with properties for the `source` object and weather the condition is true, and the `Else` method, like this

```
class Conditional<T> // or however you want to call it
{
    public T Source { get; set; } // the initial source object
    public bool Result { get; set; } // weather the IfTrue method called the action

    public void Else(Action<T> action)
    {
        if (!Result)
            action(Source);
    }
}
```

and change `IfTrue` to be like this

```
Conditional<T> IfTrue<T>(this T source, Func<T, bool> shouldPerform, Action<T> action) {
    if (shouldPerform(source)) {
        action(source);
        return new Conditional<T> { Source = source, Result = true };
    }
    return new Conditional<T> { Source = source, Result = false };
}
```

Comment: True, but then if I **wouldn't** need else part, I would need to write additional action: `someObject.IfTrue(...).Source`

Comment: Alright, now I understand what you're trying to do. But you're going to have to store the result of the `shouldPerform` somewhere...